# Control jQuery resizeable handles when clicked on and out of relevant DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I create a bunch of DIVs dynamically. I'm using jQuery resizeable handles on them.

My question is how do I make the handles appear on click/hover and make them disappear when clicked out of the relevant div?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Luq5e76g/1/)

```
$('.resizable').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('focus');
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.resizable').length) {
    $('.resizable').removeClass('focus');
  }
});
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sjchn0L8/1/

Comment: exactly, thanks. post and I'll give you a +15. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind it with a click or a hover.

Click:

```js
$('.resizable').resizable({
    handles: 'se'
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//how do I get the below working? These $('.resizable') DIV are created dynamically

$('.resizable').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('focus');
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.resizable').length) {
    $('.resizable').removeClass('focus');
  }
});
```

```css
.resizable{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.resizable.focus {
    background: #f0f;
}

.resizable .ui-resizable-handle {
    background-color: black;
    display: none !important;
}
.resizable.focus .ui-resizable-handle {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="dragDiv1" class="resizable"></div>

<div id="dragDiv2" class="resizable"></div>

<div id="dragDiv3" class="resizable"></div>
```

Or, if you want the hover, just replace the `.resizable.focus` with `.resizable:hover`. http://jsfiddle.net/sjchn0L8/2/

Comment: How do I maintain handles only on the clicked DIV?  E.g.: If `id="dragDiv1"` handle is visible, and I click `id="dragDiv3"` how would I remove the handles on `id="dragDiv1"` so the handles are now only on `id="dragDiv3"`?

Comment: @Fergoso You'd add something like `$(this).siblings().removeClass('focus');` to your click function.